Use mouse left click event handler inside a table view
I want to use TableView to display data and then use an EventHandler to perform actions after I left click on the displayed data.
When I set the TableViews Enable option to False the EventHandler ignores my left-clicks on the displayed data. When I set Enable option to True, left-clicking selects the cell and double-clicking edits the cell.
I used {MouseClicked, 2} to test and it works fine. {MouseClicked, 1} doesn't work though.
Is there any way to create a working left-click-EventHandler inside the TableView?
data = {{"Test 1", "Test 2"}, {"Test 3", "Test 4"}};
Map[EventHandler[#, {"MouseClicked", 1} :> Speak["Yeah the Event Handler works"]] &, data, {2}];
TableView[data, Enabled -> False]


Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! You are actually not doing anything with your EventHandler at all! Note that Map doesn't change the symbol, it returns a new one, so you have to write data = Map[..., data] to actually use it. But then you will se that TableView won't even show up, because EventHandler likely isn't supported in TableView.

You could wrap the whole TableView in EventHandler, but you'll have trouble determining which cell was actually clicked ... EventHandler[TableView[data, Enabled -> False], {"MouseClicked", 1} :> (Echo[MousePosition["EventHandlerScaled"]])].

I suggest you clarify what your final goal is here actually, so that we can perhaps find a better alternative. For example, using Button works: TableView[{{Button["test", Echo["test"]]}}, Expression], but EventHandler not: TableView[{{EventHandler["test", "MouseDown" :> (Echo["test"])]}}, Expression]
